# Solving a weird differential equation with y in the exponent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation

$$
xy'=y-4xe^{2y/x}
$$

I can't clasify it to any of the differential equation types. I am new in differential equations, how can I solve this ?

Comment: How about $y(x)=-\frac{1}{2} x \log (8 \log (x)+\text{Const})$ ?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I think the OP is asking for _how_ to go about solving this ODE.

Comment: Btw, it's a homogeneous ODE: after dividing both sides of equations by $x$ you get equation of type $y' = f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Make life easier writing first $$e^{\frac{2y}x}=z\implies y=\frac{1}{2} x \log (z)\implies y'=\frac{x z'}{2 z}+\frac{1}{2} \log (z)$$ So, the differential equation becomes $$\frac{x^2 z'}{2 z}+4 x z=0\implies \frac{x z'}{2 z}+4 z=0 $$ which is separable.

Comment: is the answer y = +/- x^2

Comment: @Harton. Show your results for $z$, please.

Comment: I am using the other answer as a method

Comment: @Harton. There are many methods ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$ y' = \frac{y}{x} - 4 e^{2y/x} $$

$x \neq 0$. Put $u = \frac{y}{x}$, then $y' = u'x + u $ and thus

$$ u'x + u = u - 4 e^{2u} \implies u' x = - e^{2u}$$

This equation is $\mathbf{separable}$ and you should be able to solve it!

Comment: Beat me to it +1.

Comment: where did y′=u′x+u come from ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be y' = u-4e^(2u)

Comment: is the answer y = +/- x^2

Answer (score 0):

When $\text{k}_1$ and $\text{k}_2$ are two constants:

$$xy'(x)=y(x)-\text{k}_1x\exp\left(\frac{\text{k}_2y(x)}{x}\right)$$

Let $y(x)=xr(x)$, which gives $y'(x)=r(x)+xr'(x)$:

$$x\left(r(x)+xr'(x)\right)=xr(x)-\text{k}_1x\exp\left(\frac{\text{k}_2xr(x)}{x}\right)$$

Simplify and solve for $r'(x)$:

$$x\left(r(x)+xr'(x)\right)=x\left(r(x)-\text{k}_1\exp\left(\text{k}_2r(x)\right)\right)\Longleftrightarrow r'(x)=-\frac{\text{k}_1\exp\left(\text{k}_2r(x)\right)}{x}$$

Divide both sides by $\exp\left(\text{k}_2r(x)\right)$:

$$\frac{r'(x)}{\exp\left(\text{k}_2r(x)\right)}=-\frac{\text{k}_1}{x}$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\int\frac{r'(x)}{\exp\left(\text{k}_2r(x)\right)}\space\text{d}x=\int-\frac{\text{k}_1}{x}\space\text{d}x$$

Now, use:

1. Substitute $u=-\text{k}_2r(x)$ and $\text{d}u=-\text{k}_2r'(x)\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\int\frac{r'(x)}{\exp\left(\text{k}_2r(x)\right)}\space\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{\text{k}_2}\int\exp\left(u\right)\space\text{d}u=-\frac{\exp\left(u\right)}{\text{k}_2}+\text{C}=\text{C}-\frac{1}{\text{k}_2\exp\left(\text{k}_2r(x)\right)}$$
2. $$\int-\frac{\text{k}_1}{x}\space\text{d}x=-\text{k}_1\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x=\text{C}-\text{k}_1\ln\left|x\right|$$

So, we get:

$$-\frac{1}{\text{k}_2\exp\left(\text{k}_2r(x)\right)}=\text{C}-\text{k}_1\ln\left|x\right|$$

Now, set $r(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x}$ back:

$$-\frac{1}{\text{k}_2\exp\left(\frac{\text{k}_2y(x)}{x}\right)}=\text{C}-\text{k}_1\ln\left|x\right|$$

Solving $y(x)$ (when $x\in\mathbb{R}$):

$$y(x)=\frac{x}{\text{k}_2}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1}{\text{C}+\text{k}_1\text{k}_2\ln\left|x\right|}\right)$$